# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'True'

Tags: python, django

I migrate application from sqlite3 to MYSQL : initially TABLE field was bool type in sqlite3 after migration table files changed (bool to tinyint in mysql).

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/PROJECT/apps/accounts/decorators.py" in inner_decorator
  44.                     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/PROJECT/apps/reports/views.py" in hiv_report_new
  98.         return form.get_itable(pk)
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/PROJECT/apps/reports/forms.py" in get_itable
  665.             data = cursor.execute(query)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  86.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  207.         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _warning_check
  117.                     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

Exception Type: Warning at /reports/
Exception Value: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'True'
```

Comment: Wait a second, what is `pk` exactly in your view? The line `return form.get_itable(pk)` is the *only* line in your traceback that passes a value to your query. And what does `get_itable()` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tinyint column doesn't accept booleans, convert the boolean to an integer:

```
intvalue = int(boolean_value)
```

to store `0` or `1` for `False` and `True`, respectively.

In the other direction, `0` and `1` test as false and true in boolean contexts, so you don't *have* to convert them back. You can still do so if you want, with `bool()`.